# Comparing the images of two scanned forms

Tags: image, algorithm, image-processing

I am comparing two handwritten forms (scanned images), to see if they are the same form. They could have slightly different lighting, slightly different positions, etc.

What is the best and fastest algorithm to determine if the two images are the same?

I have looked up a few algorithms and papers, but it seems that none of them would fit specifically for this task.

P.S. The images are 2 scans of the same image, which is handwritten and might be in cursive, so I am not sure if an OCR program would recognize the writing. Also, speed is quite important.

Comment: To be sure - they are two different scans of the same handwritten document? As opposed to the same FORM filled in by two different people at different times?

Comment: There is no such thing as "best and fastest algorithm" for this because it is an open problem and its characteristics are problem-dependent. Can you actually include some of such images you want to compare ?